# How to use Jack Audio Connection Kit to start/end an audio player software

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10 and Jack Audio Connection Kit.

I can use Jack (through qjackctl) with MuseScore to start/stop the MIDI playback of any MIDI song, with the internal MuseScore synthesizer and/or and external MIDI devices.

To get this, I just have to click on the [PLAY] button on the qjackctl GUI.

But... I don't have got to start/end some audio player app (like MPlayer or AlsaPlayer) at the same time I click that [PLAY] button.

When I click the qjackctl [PLAY] button..., MuseScore starts, but not the audio player app.

What did I miss?

What do I have to do to get this?